# Problem Claiming miles (Star Alliance) operated by SK

Tags: loyalty-programs, lufthansa, star-alliance, miles-and-more, sas

I had a roundtrip flight with Lufthansa to US via Frankfurt. This was four flights in total. So far I managed to claim all my miles from the first 3 flights however the final flight from FRA to ARN was impossible to claim, as there are some technical problems with the ticket.

1) I am trying to add the miles into my A3 *A account.
2) The segment from FRA to ARN was operated by SAS (although the ticket was issued by LH).

3) My ticket number is 220 XXXXXXXXX ie typical for LH.

It seems to me that A3 system that counts the miles is confused by this situation. Do you know how should I properly claim this segment's miles through A3? Any Ideas?

Should I put into A3 system that flight was by SK and ticket number 220 XXXX?

This is very confusing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to credit a Star Alliance flight to a Star Alliance bonus program. What counts here is the airline that *operates* the flight, which is SAS in your case.

Who issued the ticket does not really matter. You should be able to claim miles if you did not fly in any of the fare classes I, R, X, N, or F (according to the current version of https://en.aegeanair.com/milesandbonus/how-to-earn/all-airlines/) - the others should work.

To claim miles, visit the site https://en.aegeanair.com/milesandbonus/my-account/claim-missing-miles/ and fill out the form. Leave out the booking reference if you want. If your SK flight was booked under a Lufthansa flight number (as a co-share flight), you should exclude the booking class as well as it is non-obvious to which SAS booking class you LH booking class for the flight would map to. Fortunately, you do not have to provide it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So you suggest that I should put the SKXXXX flight number in that form and at the same time LH's ticket number ?

Comment: @MdPlrst Yes, there is simply no reason why that would be a problem. It would be insightful to know why you expect problems. If you used https://en.aegeanair.com/milesandbonus/miles-calculator/ to try to calculate earned miles, note that that page is for Aegean/Olympic flights only, so an error message only indicates that they do not serve the route.

Comment: Hmm, i called Lufthansa they told me that SK class is E, so i am entitled of miles. Meanwhile A3 site gives me this: 318-Your request has been rejected, due to incorrect origin and /or destination port. Please check the details request again or contact us

Comment: @MdPlrst If the form on the A3 website does not work correctly, you may have to contact them for mileage credit. Wouldn't be the first time that not all possibilities are correctly implemented in a retrocredit online form.